# Database design - both Member + Family models has_many Address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

I'm having some trouble thinking about the best way to structure my database. I have two models, one related to another, that both need an `Address`.

```
 class Family < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :address
 end
 class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :address
   belongs_to :family
 end
```

The reason being a `Family` might have an address (e.g. home), and then individual members may have their own addresses (e.g. work). What does the `Address` model look like? Does it have foreign keys for both `Member` and `Family`? Do I make another class to sit in the middle?

Comment: You need to read up on "polymorphic associations". You can easily find tons of tutorials online, also in Rails active record documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Please look the diagram

Entity is a superclass, person and organization extends entity.

Both persons and organizations area related to many address, but save the information about this relation in only one place.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWCyO.png